# Proper Free video editor to make video with movable the some flash or ... during the video

Tags: video-editor, flash

I have seen this video in YouTube:

[image]

And like to know about free editor to built this video kind for my own.
So i asked here is any free software for ding this work, combining the video with flash or photo to move during the video ruining.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, and has many answers that people have put time and effort into posting. Please do some research, like searching this site for "free software", and if you have specific questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: try: https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+software